# Setting up Emacs/AUCTeX viewer

Tags: latex, auctex, linux

I have installed AUCTeX, it compiled a test file OK, but I can't view the output.

I get " Cannot get Evince viewer ...". Xviewer, should be the analogue in my distro, I think (I have not way to check through TeXworks as it uses an integrated viewer), as that is what I use to view pdf files.

I tried M-x customize-variable  TeX-view-program-list  following the instruction of a [related post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106889/change-view-command-in-emacs-and-auctex-pdf-mode#107565).

Then under INS, I put as 'name' Xreader. What should I put in the other fields? [image]

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sylvia
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `xreader` is the name of the executable then Command should be `xreader %o` and Viewer Executable should be `xreader`.

Comment: I did that, and then I was ask to set TeX-view-program-selection to xreader, and put Xreader under View. It worked.